# Пропорциональное изменение высоты и позиционирование <a> или просто текста

Tags: javascript, css

Есть два блока, которые при прокрутке страницы остаются фиксированным, на определённом моменте при скроллинге, первый блок исчезает, второй занимает его место. Нужно сделать так, чтобы текст во втором блоке оставался по середине, так как он перемещается немного вверх. Пробовал на `javascript` менять, `top:...;` не получается текст съезжает, а нужно чтобы он перемещался автоматически без съезжания, прямо как на сайте `transparency.org`. Дело всё в том, что там ещё меняется высота блока, вот и получается, что изменение высоты происходит, а текст не находиться горизонтально по середине, а конкретно там ссылки. Текст в общем, перемещается немного вверх, позиционирование хромает. Нужно чтобы текст был по середине, также как и до скроллинга.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$(window).scroll(function() {


    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {

        $("#top-buttons-panel").hide();
          /*$('.top-nav').addClass('scroll');*/


        $(".top-nav").addClass("compressed"); 
        $("#top-buttons-panel").height($("#top-buttons-panel")/5);
    }
    else {

        $("#top-buttons-panel").show();


        $(".top-nav").removeClass("compressed");
        /*$('.top-nav').removeClass('scroll');*/

    }


});
```

Comment: можно пример с этим багом

Comment: примеры **кода**, а не картинки

Comment: а нужно чтобы, кроме изменения ширины, текст оставался также в середине, как и в первом случае, у меня получается только съезжание, а резкое изменение нет, то есть автоматическое как бы. Как на transparency.org

Comment: Это js, но это само ичезание блока, а мне нужно понять как сделать только позиционирование текста, хотя может и по другому можно или я просто чего то не понимаю

Comment: в стилях compressed, только изменение высоты Height: 30%, правда она не рабоает

Comment: в общем нужно, чтобы текст при скроллинге во втором блоке тоже был по середение, а не съезжал до и после скроллинга в противоположные стороны

Comment: я перелопатил много материала, но всё что я нашел это решение проблемы с помощью анимации, по сути сезжани блока и его расширение. А мне нужно чтобы происходило автоматическое изменение с сохранением центрирования текста по горизонтали, а не съезжание, вот и получается, что не получается)))